# inner div fill rest of screen (limited by wrapper margin & padding)

Tags: css, html

I need the content div to 'fill' the remainder of the screen left over after the header. I would would like to keep the wrapper padding & margin. Using absolute position doesn't work as the content div stops being visually nested in the wrapper. (The header div can be a fixed height if absolutely necessary, however I would prefer it to be dynamic.) Many thanks.

```
* { 
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
}

html, 
body { 
height: 100%;
}


#wrapper {
    background-color:#eee; 
    margin:20px; padding:20px;
    border: solid 1px #333;
}

#header {

}

#content {
     background-color:red;
}
```

.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="content">content</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jHLhK/

Answer (score 0):

Specify width and height set to `100%` to your content div.

```
#content {
     background-color:red;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
}
```

The `100%` means it will be as much as it has space available from surrounding elements.

Or you may only want `height` or only `width` to be `100%` depending on your requirement.

Comment: this creates no visual change. In the example code, I'd like the remainder of the page to be filled with red after the header.